# Help understanding an audio processing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, signal-processing

I'm reading [“Speech segmentation without speech recognition” by Dong Wang, Lie Lu and Hong-Jiang Zhang](http://bero.freqvibez.net/public/segs/icassp03_senseg.pdf).
The algorithm I'm looking at is a V/C/P (Vowel/Consonant/Pause) classification algorithm on a digital speech signal. It is described as such:

1. Audio data is segmented into 20ms-long non-overlapping frames, 
   where features, including ZCR, Energy and Pitch, are extracted.
2. Energy and pitch curve is smoothed.
3. The  `Mean_En` and  `Std_En` of energy curve are calculated to 
   coarsely estimate the background noise energy level, as:

   ```
   NoiseLevel = Mean_En - 0.75 Std_En.
   ```

   Similarly the threshold of ZCR (`ZCR_dyna`) is defined as:

   ```
   ZCR_dyna = Mean_ZCR + 0.5 Std_ZCR
   ```
4. Frames are classified as V/C/P coarsely by using the following 
   rules, where FrameType is used to denote the type of each frame.

   ```
   If ZCR > ZCR_dyna then FrameType = Consonant 
   Else if Energy < NoiseLevel, then  FrameType = Pause 
   Else FrameType = Vowel
   ```
5. Update the `NoiseLevel` as the weighted average energy of the 
   frames at each vowel boundary and the background segments.
6. Re-classify the frames using algorithm in step 4 with the updated 
   `NoiseLevel`. Pauses are merged by removing isolated short 
   consonants. Vowel will be split at its energy valley if its duration is 
   too long

I do not understand step #5. Like I don't know how to interpret the wording - is there another way to describe what they are doing? I get that we want to update the `NoiseLevel` variable and re-run step #4 for every frame, I just don't understand how exactly.

Comment: Maybe you can ask the authors for clarification?

Comment: Yeah I can try that, though I was hoping it would be obvious to someone else so I could get a quicker response =)